# How to get start and end posion of an mshtml.IHTMLSelectionObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, selection, mshtml

here's my code :

```
var doc = webBrowser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
            if (doc != null)
            {
                var currentSelection = doc.selection;
                if (currentSelection != null)
                {
                    var selectionRange = currentSelection.createRange();
```

can I get the start and end position of `selectionRange` ?

Comment: Selections are not necessarily simple.  Consider [getBoundingClientRect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IHTMLTxtRange CurrentSelection
{
    get
    {
        var htmlDocument = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = htmlDocument.selection;
        IHTMLTxtRange range = null;
        if (currentSelection != null)
        {
            range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            //range.moveStart("wdCell",1);
            //range.moveEnd("wdCell",1);
        }
        return range;
    }
}
```

[Range.MoveStart Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.movestart%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
[Programmatically Extend Ranges in Documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsb2ey6.aspx)
[WdUnits Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdunits%28v=office.11%29.aspx)